# how do I enable the root user from the Directory Utility?

Tags: macos, root, ldap, directory-utility

How do I [enable the root account](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204012)?  I don't see any options related the system user.  Do I enter the server as "localhost"?

[image: utility]

[image: ldap]

What do I select here?

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version:   OS X 10.10.2 (14C1510)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 14.1.0
  Boot Volume:  Mac OSx
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    A MacBook Pro
  User Name:    thufir (thufir)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  Time since boot:  1:03


Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro9,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.3 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP91.00D3.B08
  SMC Version (system): 2.1f175
  Serial Number (system):   C02HH5JQDV33
  Hardware UUID:    FBB1FF0A-6EAC-5423-9E8F-405B181EF5F3
  Sudden Motion Sensor:
  State:    Enabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put anything in there if you're working locally, just click 'Open Directory Utility' [which you did, based on your second pic]

Then…
Edit menu - Enable root user [only available once you unlock Directory Utility, which it looks like you did]

...I would wonder why you need root unlocked - you really don't need it in OS X, you can sudo anyway

Comment: didn't know osx had sudo...   sudo works fine...

Answer (score 1):

By default, the root user is disabled on Mac, and you need to follow the steps below in order to enable/disable/change password for root user on Mac. Refer https://www.dataneb.com/single-post/2018/08/29/How-to-enable-root-user-on-Mac

1. From top left hand side, choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups (or Accounts).
2. Click the lock icon , then enter an administrator name and password.
3. After you unlock the lock. Click Login Options, right next to home icon.
4. Now Click Join (or Edit), right next to Network Account Server. Now Click Open Directory Utility.
5. Click lock icon in the Directory Utility window, then enter an administrator name and password.
6. From the menu bar in Directory Utility: Choose Edit > Enable Root User, then enter the password that you want to use for the root user. You can enable/disable/change password for root user from here.